# Деплой двух Django проектов на Nginx - gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, nginx, gunicorn

Как написать gunicorn.service что-бы он запускал сразу два django проекта или подскажите другие варианты как это сделать с помощью gunicorn. Хочу разместить два проекта на vps, на 2 субдомена с помощью nginx-gunicorn.
С Nginx вроде всё понятно, а вот с Gunicorn не могу разобраться ((

Comment: Напишите два отдельных сервиса да и всё

Answer (score 2):

Запускать два разных приложения в одном gunicorn [не поддерживается](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/35) из коробки.

Способ которым вам стоит воспользоваться это запуск двух gunicorn на разных портах - каждый с одним приложением и соответствующая конфигурация nginx, чтобы запросы к разным (под)доменам или портам направлялись к двум разным gunicorn-ам.

Comment: Это гениально, спасибо!